# How to open an App from a link in email?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have to open my App from a link in email .that is when registering in my App,i got a mail contains a link something like: `click for open your app`.so when i click the link from my mobile browser i need  the app  Launched.Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK is not possible atm. Unless you use a push notification.
This should help

[Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) 
[How to: Set Up a Notification Channel for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402556%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) 
[How to: Send a Push Notification for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: You'd have to have the link connect to a webserver which would then trigger the push notification. The only appropriate notification would be a toast which the user would then have to tap on which would then open the app. That sounds like more effort than is worth it to me.

Comment: PN isn't always perfectly timed, so there can be a delay between when the PN is requested and when it is actually sent to the device. With such an inconsistency, PN may not be a good way of having the app launch 'automatically'.

Comment: It could be so easy but MS often unhinders developers writing good apps. App is installed (and verified by MS) by user and so the user trust that app. I don't see a reason why it should not possible launching an app (and providing parameters) by clicking a link in an e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Just include instructions to open the app in the email if need be.

Comment: What instructions are included in the link?if you know the code please help me.is there any way to launch app by using its app id?

Comment: @Sujiz It isn't possible I meant you could inlcude soem text to say go and open the app. Or you coudl inlcude a link to the app in the marketplace if they don't have it installed.

Comment: It wasn't available in Mango then and isn't avaialble in it now.